# VC++ 2008/2010: is throw() or __declspec(nothrow) a better choice?

Tags: visual-c++, exception, throw, declspec

When using VC++ 2008 and 2010, which marker is better to use to indicate a function won't throw exceptions:

- `throw()` (C++ standard)
- `__declspec(nothrow)` (MS extension)

I read a few older forum discussions where people said that using `throw()` may actually force the compiler to generate additional code to catch exceptions in case the function does throw (against the marker). Their advice is not to use `throw()` but use `__declspec(nothrow)` instead, since the compiler can actually use it for optimization.

I did some searches but I couldn't come up with really useful results. From how I understand, the Boost library advises against using them [here](http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html#Exception-specification). `__declspec(nothrow)` is non-standard C++, so if MS implements exception specifications, it'll keep working the same way while the `throw()` behavior may change.

Comment: Related: [Is there any use for C++ throw decoration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410226/is-there-any-use-for-c-throw-decoration), [Throw keyword in function's signature (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055387/throw-keyword-in-functions-signature-c), [What is the point of `void func() throw(type)`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589459/what-is-the-point-of-void-func-throwtype), [Why aren't exceptions in C++ checked by the compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037575/why-arent-exceptions-in-c-checked-by-the-compiler). Personally, I'd say "neither".

Comment: Exception specification isnt very useful in c++: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, I was searching for nothrow and __declspec, I couldn't find much that way.

Comment: CodyGray: Please note that all those questions are now dated by a new standard, that significantly changes the allowed optimizations.

Comment: Related: [Why add a throw() to your methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/03/22/558390.aspx). The comments in this blog post are worth reading as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard form is `noexcept`, but VC++ 2008 and 2010 don't support this.

Personally, I'd use a macro, defined as `throw()` (or maybe even nothing) until compilers start supporting C++11 `noexcept`, and then change it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I chose to use __declspec(nothrow) since the VC++ compiler can use that to actually optimize away unneeded exception code.