# C++ method declaration with throw(...)

Tags: c++, methods, throw

I have a question regarding declaration class method in C++. I usually using declaration method without providing throw (will throw anything). But I saw somewhere declaration like this:

`void method(int param) throw (...);`

Does it have any sense? What is difference?

Comment: Do you mean `throw (...)` literally? Or `throw (something here)`? If the latter then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589459/what-is-the-point-of-void-func-throwtype (which appears right there at the top of the "Related" list, as it did whilst you were writing your question).

Comment: I mean throw(...) literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Microsoft extension, which basically means "This function may throw something", which is equivalent to having no specification at all. The value of adding it is questionable.

Comment: For completeness: it also works with Clang 3.5 for me, but not with `g++ -fms-extensions`.

Answer (score 3):

Well [it's not valid C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b71fa786c29534fb) so, no, it doesn't "have any sense":

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:1:31: error: expected type-specifier before '...' token
 void method(int param) throw (...);
```

<sup>([nor in C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/228ad58f596abaac))</sup>

The only place you can write `...` in an exception specifier is after the *type-id* in a *dynamic-exception-specification* in order to form a pack expansion (`[C++11: 15.4/16]`), [like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d56776e11712bdb):

```
template <typename ...T>
void method(int param) throw (T...) {}

int main()
{
    method<int, bool>(42);
    // ^ somewhat like invoking a `void method(int) throw(int, bool)`
}
```